# MATLAB date number too short - how to get MATLAB to stop shortening my Serial Date Number

Tags: matlab, date, short

I need to extract the dates from a set of data `s`.

I use the command `s(x).comm.date` where x can be changed for each person however it is returning the serial date number as `7.3244e+005` which just gives me the day but I need it to show much more detail something like this `732162.65994213`.

I don't know if the data I have is already saving it as the shorthand format but it's a set of data from MIT and the help documentation shows it as the long hand format so I sincerely doubt this.

Yours,
MATLAB Newbie

Comment: Does it help if you type 'format long' in the matlab command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try typing the following `help format` or `format long` (for starters).

By default, Matlab displays 5 significant digits (calculations are done in appropriate floating-point precision, no matter how those variables are displayed). Refer to the documentation for different ways of [displaying](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/format.html).

Comment: That is showing the full one now thanks alot!

I couldn't find how to do this using help docs, so cheers.